# Удалить дубли из таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, есть таблица (40К записей). Есть дублирующие записи. Нужно их удалить, оставив одну оригинальную.

Делаю так (сравниваю по столбцу `name`)

```
delete from `admin_eda`.`eda` 
where `eda`.`id` not in (
                         select min(`eda`.`id`) 
                         from `admin_eda`.`eda` 
                         group by `eda`.`name`
                        )
```

Выдает

```
#1093 - Не допускается указание таблицы 'eda' в списке таблиц FROM для внесения в нее изменений
```

Comment: Нельзя одновременно изменять таблицу и делать по ней же выборку в подзапросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конвертируйте подзапрос в представление (view), и ограничение не сработает. А вью потом удалите, операция-то одноразовая...

```
CREATE VIEW select_min_id_from_eda
AS
SELECT MIN(`eda`.`id`) min_id
FROM `admin_eda`.`eda` 
GROUP BY `eda`.`name`;

DELETE FROM `admin_eda`.`eda` 
WHERE `eda`.`id` 
  NOT IN ( SELECT min_id
           FROM select_min_id_from_eda
         );

DROP VIEW select_min_id_from_eda;
```

Comment: В View? Как? Что?

Comment: @Flippy [view](https://habrahabr.ru/post/47031/)

Comment: @Akina  а есть разница между View и Temporary table с движком Memory? это не одно и то же? просто для инфы)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, совсем даже не одно и то же, хотя по работе чем-то схожи. View можно считать динамической автоматически строящейся временной таблицей. Во всяком случае в MySQL (старшие "братья" обычно умеют встраивать текст вью в запрос, и не всегда это благо). В зависимости от размера выборки она может полностью поместиться в памяти, а может и материализоваться на диск (чем выгодно отличается от темптабле, где либо память, либо диск, как укажешь). С другой стороны, каждое обращение к вью приводит к новому построению набора его записей, тогда как темптабле можно использовать повторно.